# C2DM - Message sent successful from server, but not showing up on device

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

I was hoping I won't get to this, but I have been busting my head for the past 2 days with something that looks pretty simple. I have already implemented my C2DM application client + server, following the tutorials from [google](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=es-ES#receiving) and [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html).

I will try to describe my problem briefly:

1. My client application **successfully** receives its **registrationId**.
2. My server **successfully** receives its **authentication token**.
3. The server sends a message using its **authentication token** and the device's **registrationId**.
4. When sending a message from the server to the client, I get a successful message response code (e.g. *id=0:1335303367614556%fd55792500000030 Response code: 200*, which per Google's documentation on C2DM should be a successful message).

So I figure that most probably my problem is with my receiver for the messages, because they are sent from my third party server to the C2DM server, but cannot get from there to my application.

**I read on related topics on StackOverflow that the problem might be with the port on the device, but I am currently using the same receiver for both registering the application and receiving messages, and the registration part works every time.**

Here is my receiver:

```
public class C2DRegistrationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action != null){
        if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")){
            // do something     
        }
        else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")){
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
}
```

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ro.raullepsa.coder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- SDK min version -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />


<!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
<permission android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive messages from Google's c2dm -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Permission to use internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity
        android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder.activity.RegistrationResultActivity" />
    <activity android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder.activity.MessageReceivedActivity" />
    <receiver 
        android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder.util.c2d.C2DRegistrationReceiver" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

        <!-- Receive messages -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Receive the registration id -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="ro.raullepsa.coder" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I get no errors, I have tried over and over again to reinstall the application, re-register, I have tried with 2 separate receivers, I have manually force-stopped all services running from C2DM and reinstalled, but still nothing.

I've tried in debug mode to wait on the first line of the receiver, and it gets there on registering, but never after I send a message from the server.

I am kind of stuck and would appreciate any help. I can provide more code if needed, although my application is basically [Lars Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html). What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried on another device?

Comment: That was my plan actually, but I haven't got another Android device that would support this. If I can't manage, I will borrow a friend's device and try on his.

Comment: I think it's an important step as it helps narrow the problem and rule out an issue with one device. Also try it on a different network (3G instead of wifi) - I have seen C2DM messages fail to arrive on some networks (though as you can register ok, this probably isn't the issue).

Comment: Would also be interesting to see if that device can receive C2DM messages to other apps - e.g. WhatsApp or whatever.

Comment: I was using WhatsApp and it worked ok. My application now runs successfully (or at least, that's how it seems to be now). See my answer for more details. I am guessing that maybe the local network was causing problems, if you say you saw this kind of behavior before. Thanks anyway for your comments !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something interesting happened. Although I didn't make any changes in the code from the previous night, when I woke up this morning and turned on the Wifi I received a message.

Now everything works fine. As soon as I send a message I automatically get in on the device. (and yes, my Wifi was also on last night)

I am not sure what caused the delay, as I was receiving a positive response code from the Google servers but nothing on my device. Probably it took some time to send the first message? I am not sure.

I tried on other Wifi networks and it also works. Hope I won't bump into this anymore. Still, I find the behavior somehow strange.

Comment: My experience of C2DM is that it is unreliable by nature. It works pretty well most of the time, but all apps that use it should be designed to cope with messages not arriving - so some kind of slow background poll is likely to be necessary

Answer (score 1):

GCM notification coming to your device as background data.

Enable your background data, which is in

> Settings>Account and Sync> Background data